Coupling a single mode laser to multimode fibre - does this reduce coherance?
If I have a single mode laser coupled to a multimode fibre with imperfect overlap between the laser mode and the fibre core, the light will propagate in several LP modes.
In this case, does the light exciting from the fibre have a reduced coherence compared to the original laser, as the laser is now effectively multi-modal?
However, if I perfectly couple/overlap the laser mode to the fibre LP01 mode, the light exciting the fibre should still be single mode (albeit with attenuation).
So - am I correct in saying the coherence of the light output from the fibre is highly dependent on the coupling into the fibre?
